# How to store the large volume of steaming data in sqllite for a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, mobile

I am building a mobile appfor Reporting and Business Intelligence. The app will show a live stream of billing, payments and other data to management of a company which is doing business across 70 different physical locations. The idea is to see what is happening in the business across all locations as a live stream on line graphs on your tablet.

However the question I have in mind is that with billing and payments data across 70 locations, this stream of data will be huge, and continuous. Over 1 year this dataset will exceed 10GB. Should so much of information be kept in a sqllite database on a mobile? Are there any best practises on handling such large datasets on a mobile app? Tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large databases you should use Realm. It is noSql db and it is more efficient with large data sets. But, more importantly, you can store realm database as ordinary file on SD card. 
As I understood from your description, you need to store very large volume of data, but you don't have to access any portion of it (access latest data immediately and previous data with some delay).
You can create system's architecture in that way, so there will be 'database adapter' for Realm, which will take one file, extract data from it, convert it to anther format (in background, of coarse) and then upload those data to AWS or any other cloud storage.
If you use Realm, you can just monitor file size (database is ordinary file), and, if it exceeds given value, create new database file and process previous file in the way I mentioned. 
Another approach - interpolate your data and save interpolation factors, but there is math envolved and some data will be lost.

Comment: Tx for making me aware about Realm

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, all data is kept on remote server, and you uploading some pieces when you need it. Don't know if it's what you searching from.